# Проблема со сборкой проекта JavaFX Maven

Tags: java, javafx, maven

Консольное приложение собирается в jar Maven-ом и запускаются без проблема, но проекты на JavaFX после сборки дают ошибку.

Выполняю:

```
java -cp testBuild-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar sample.Main
```

Ошибка:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class sample.Main
```

Конфигурация pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>testBuild</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

 <build>
     <plugins>
         <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
             <configuration>
                 <source>1.8</source>
                 <target>1.8</target>
             </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
             <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
             <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>2.0</version>
             <configuration>
                 <mainClass>sample.Main</mainClass>
             </configuration>
         </plugin>
     </plugins>
 </build>
```

Main class:

```
package sample;


public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

замени 2 плагин на:

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
  <archive>
    <manifest>
      <mainClass>sample.Main</mainClass>
    </manifest>
  </archive>
  <descriptorRefs>
    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
  </descriptorRefs>
</configuration>
<executions>
  <execution>
    <id>make-assembly</id> 
    <phase>package</phase> 
    <goals>
      <goal>single</goal>
    </goals>
  </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Потом `mvn install`